# How do I save data with Hive?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am building an app and I want to save values with Hive. The goal is for the exercise1 and exercise1time values to be saved even after my app is closed. I am used Hive and `box.put()` and `box.get()` but the values aren't saving. My code is below:

```
class _homeState extends State<home> {
  
  late final Box box;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    box = Hive.box('exerciseBox');
  }

  addInfo() {
    box.put('Exercise 1', exercise1);
    box.put('Exercise 1 Time', exercise1time);
    box.flush();
    return Text("");
  }

  getInfo() {
    exercise1 = box.get('Exercise 1');
    exercise1time = box.get('Exercise 1 Time');
    return Text("");
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Hey'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          const Text(
            'Schedule:',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
          if (exercise1 != "") ...[
            addInfo(),
            getInfo(),
            one(exercise1),
```

There is more code below, but this all the Hive stuff apart from what I run in main.dart.